# Onsen 2.0 v 1.x - pure JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui, monaca

Sorry if this is a very basic question, but the documentation seems to be somewhat conflicting regarding Onsen with Monaca.  I am using Monaca cloud and I only want to use pure JS - no angular or react.  Those frameworks will add too much overhead for what I am trying to accomplish which is a very basic app.  So my question is, it appears Onsen 2.0 divests from those frameworks yet the sample template in the cloud ide somewhat indicates that you need to use angular for the flat iOS design.  If I only want to use non-framework integrated JS, which Onsen should I be using 1.x or 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use just pure JavaScript, you should choose Onsen UI 2.0
At the moment, it's the only agnostic mobile hybrid app framework on the market. Onsen UI 1.x is based on AngularJS 1.x, which is not suitable for your purpose.

Take a look at the following link if you want to learn more about Onsen UI 2.0

https://onsen.io/2/

Comment: Thank you!  That's what I figured I needed to do, but I was slightly confused by the sample template for 2.0 which I assume is to just demonstrate angular and react.

Comment: Yes exactly. Anyway should be a specific template for Onsen UI 2.0 in Monaca (should be at the end). Take a look at it!